# analysis Partita in A minor Gigue, BWV 827

Tags: analysis

I started out by hearing advice on analyzing keyboard partita before, but again I found too many questions in this Gigue.

this Gigue in 12/8 time

Let's summarize the questions with images below.

**1. I do not know the identity of the intermittent second inversion.**

[image]

The parts marked with a red box in the image are second inversion from my point of view. Because if you look at the progression with the next chord, it's not a non-chord progression.
(I wrote down the corresponding Tonality when the sound in the red box appears, cause modulation occurs a lot.)

So I'm so confused. Can a second inversion just come out like this in 2-3 part music like keyborad partita?

**2. Are these all Pedal points?**

[image]

The notes in the red box are all tied, and the tied note becomes a non-chord in the next chord, but does not progress like a suspension note. The last bar that says 46 may be anticipation note, but the strong beat is the confusing part.

If these were all Pedal points, that would be an explanation, but I'm not sure if the range of Pedal points can be short or so varied.

**3. unknown progress**

[image]

The note in the last beat of the first red box is F#-C-E

The note in the second red box is F#-E.

It may sound like a seventh, but when you look at the progression of the leading and trailing chords, the seventh is not appropriate.

It doesn't progress like a non-chord, though.

So I don't know what these are.
I hope someone can help.

The full sheet music is here.

https://musescore.com/user/4887176/scores/5592036

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're analyzing at too fine a level of detail.  There are two, maybe four harmonies in each measure, not twelve. This is a passing sonority.  It's not structural.
2. These are not pedal points.  They are suspensions.  They mostly have a delayed resolution at the beginning of the second beat, though the C♯ at the end of measure 39 resolves directly to D on the second third of beat 1 in measure 40.
3. I would call the beginning of measure 38 `iiø7` relative to E minor.  The second half of the measure is `V7`, and the downbeat of 39 is `i`.  Totally standard.  Similarly, the second half of 41 is `V7` of B (*minor*), and the downbeat of 42 is `i6`.

Comment: 1. What is passing sonority? As you say, if those notes come out not structurally, isn't that a non-harmonic note? What confuses me is that, unless that's a second inversion, it should be non-harmonic, and the progression is all made up of indiscriminate leaps that aren't present in normal non-harmonic progressions.

Comment: 2. I asked a similar question here last time and got an answer, but after the suspension note came out, the notes jumped too much, so I was confused. And I'm not sure how much delay is possible, but can it be considered until the next strong beat comes?

Comment: 3. If they are 7 chords, what are the preparations and resolutions? That's what's confusing.

Comment: @guss2222 1. "passing" is perhaps the wrong word because it seems to convey some similarity with "passing tone," which there is not.  I just mean that it is of short duration, on a weak beat, temporary.  The rules of counterpoint apply, but structurally, harmonically, the bass note is C sharp and the B is a lower neighbor embellishment. 2. Yes.  For example the middle voice at 36 has B, then C, E, A.  The C and E can be thought of as different (implied) additional accompanying voices, leaving the middle voice with B-A in dotted quarter rhythm. 3. In both instances, the preparation is...

Comment: @guss2222 ...fairly standard.  The last pitch in the right hand in measure 37 is E, and the dominant pitch of beat 2 in measure 41 is E.  The resolution is more implicit, as the following D sharps in the first case and D naturals in the second case are not in the same octave.

Comment: 1. Are you talking about the passing progression of second inversion? In that case, the base should move sequentially. and C#->B->C# That's just the first of many examples, right? What about the rest? And if B is a neighbor note, what is the neighbor note for? B cannot be a neighbor note with E. They are both harmonious.

Comment: 3. I have no idea what happened to your explanation of preparation. How the hell was that 'E' prepared in the previous chord?
And as for resolution, the D# and D you mentioned come out after skipping 2 strong beats each.
Does it mean that it is resolved with that much delay? I honestly have doubts.

Comment: @guss2222 1. B is the lower neighbor of C sharp.  Harmonically, the bass part could be a C sharp dotted quarter.  The B is there to provide melodic interest.  The harmony is `V6/iv`.  The other examples are perhaps clearer: for example in measure 12, the two hands are arpeggiating a C major 7th chord, and at the last third of the second beat, the left hand happens to be on the fifth while the right hand is on the root.  It's not useful to analyze that as a second inversion; the C at the beginning of beat two is the more important note there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139477/discussion-between-phoog-and-guss2222).

Comment: It seems that these were questions that occurred because I did not know a one simple concept. Thanks for letting me find the problem!